# Opening a form in C# without focus

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, focus

I am creating some always-on-top toasts as forms and when I open them I'd like them not to take away focus from other forms as they open. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show a Form without stealing focus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156046/show-a-form-without-stealing-focus)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation
{
    get
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Override this property in your form code and it should do the trick for you.

Comment: It should be noted that this will NOT work if your form has TopMost property set to true, to use this override with a topmost form you must override CreateParams and set WS_EX_TOPMOST on the ExStyle as well.

Answer (score 15):

It took me a few minutes using Adam's & Aaron's info above, but I finally got it to work for me.  The one thing I had to do was make sure the form's Top Most property is set to false.  Here is the code I used...

```
    protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation { get { return true; } }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            //make sure Top Most property on form is set to false
            //otherwise this doesn't work
            int WS_EX_TOPMOST = 0x00000008;
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= WS_EX_TOPMOST;
            return cp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It should also be noted that all the above works only when the form is shown with Show() -- does not work with ShowDialog()