# Instantiate form without losing focus on existing form

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework, focus

I have an application in .NET 2.0 on the compact framework.  When I instantiate my custom form the current form that I have visible seems to lose focus.  My new form isn't visible (I haven't called ShowDialog()) on it, but my current form loses focus simply by calling the constructor on my new form.  Any ideas on how to work around this? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686132/opening-a-form-in-c-without-focus) question seemed similar but there is no ShowWithoutActivation property on the compact framework.

Comment: You could always re-assert focus of your current form right afterwards. It's kind of a hack but probably will work for you.

Comment: I thought about that, but I have a couple problems:
1) The code creating the second form isn't aware of the first form (and shouldn't have to be).  I don't really have a chance to do this in the calling code either where the first form is known.
2) There would still be a "flicker" as the first form loses and regains focus.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using WinApi specific code will help:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.Style |= WindowStyle.WS_POPUP;
        cp.ExStyle |= ExStyle.WS_EX_TOPMOST | ExStyle.WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
        return cp;
     }
}
```

Comment: That looks like it would be pretty useful, but the `CreateParams` property doesn't exist in the compact framework.