# How to open form under the active form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, window

In .Net WinForms I have two forms. Form1 is open and active. How can I open new form (Form2) that:

- Form1 must have focus
- Form2 is opened under Form1 (background Form1)

First point is simple see [stackoverflow...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686132/opening-a-form-in-c-sharp-without-focus?rq=1)
But I don't know how to show Form2 under Form1.
Thanks.

**EDIT**

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 frm;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frm = new Form2();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Focus();
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.AddOwnedForm(frm);
        frm.Show();
        frm.SendToBack();
        this.BringToFront();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm.Show();
        frm.SendToBack();
        this.BringToFront();
    }

}
```

Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Focus();
    }

    protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            //make sure Top Most property on form is set to false
            //otherwise this doesn't work
            int WS_EX_TOPMOST = 0x00000008;
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= WS_EX_TOPMOST;
            return cp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean showing the forms side by side then you would have to set the size and position of the forms.

Comment: No, I mean setting Z-order of Form2. I want to still Form1 on the top, but I cannot set Form1 as TOP MOST (because Form1 can be another Form from application). The point is: every automaticaly (programmatically) opened Form must be open under active Form (Form1 in this case) not TOP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for second point what you need to do is this:

```
var form2 = new Form2();
    form2.MdiParent = form1; //form1 is your parent form; use this operator in case you are creating this form from out base form

    form2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    form2.Show();
```

Please have a look at this for further details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdiparent.aspx

EDIT

Please see below code which gives an appearance that frm is open on top of Form1.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 frm;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frm = new Form2();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        textBox1.Focus();
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!frm.Visible)
        {
          this.AddOwnedForm(frm);
          frm.Show();
          frm.SendToBack();
          this.BringToFront();
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.AddOwnedForm(frm);
        frm.Show();
        frm.SendToBack();
        this.BringToFront();
    }

}
```

Comment: But I don't want to create MDI form! Forms which will be opened are more than one and from different locations code. This is short example what I want to do.

Comment: I think in order to view multiple forms under a single parent form, you have to use Multiple Document Interface. you can set your current parent form to have MdiChilds as follows: this.IsMdiContainer = true; and then set form2.MdiParent to this;
Else, other way to do this is by using ShowDialog(). However, ShowDialog would restrict the number of forms to 2 only.

Comment: Problem is I cannot use MDI, because the application is modular application from another company and I make one module to this application. So I application is not MDI and I cannot use this.

Comment: Please try this. var form2 = new Form2();
this.AddOwnedForm(form2);
form2.Show(); Let me know if this works for you.
You can remove the form by using this.RemoveOwnedForm(form2); once form2 is closed.

Comment: No, still not working. Here is simple test code: http://www.ulozto.cz/xUjSyrb/topmostwindow-zip

Comment: I am unable to access this site. Could you please edit that code in your question?

Comment: I saw your code. If you want to show Form2 on button click then, please transfer the code from timer1_Tick to button1_Click. You can change your timer1_Tick code by adding additional check as follows:if (!form2.Visible){ //code }. This would prevent the form2 opening multiple times.

Comment: The timer only simulating opening Form2 from code from another part of application. I tried to transfer code to event of button1, but still Form2 is opened above Form1.

Comment: try to add line this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized above this.AddOwnedForm(form2); line. Remember, this would only give appearance that form2 is under form1 but I am afraid it is not possible to create form under parent form without MDI.

Comment: This only maximized Form1. No changes.

Comment: The code runs ok at my end. It shows form1 maximized with form2 on top of that.

Comment: You open Form2 under Form1 - Form1 is on TOP MOST?

Comment: Yes. Form2 is displayed as small rectangle along with Form1 which is maximised with focus set on Form2.

Comment: After tests it si working but I have to change:
`this.AddOwnedForm(form2);` to `form2.AddOwnedForm(this);`

Answer (score 0):

You simply instantiate the Form2 and show it, eg:

```
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.Visible = true;
```

Then you set Form1 to be the active form (assuming this is done in Form1's code - hence the `this`):

```
this.BringToFront();
```

Comment: I tried this and it's not working. In the Form1 I created Form2:

 Form2 frm = new Form2();
            frm.Visible = true;
            this.BringToFront();

Comment: Well just use `form2.SendToBack();`

Answer (score 0):

I conjecture that you want a dialog

```
var form2 = new Form2(); 
form2.Visible = true; 
this.ShowDialog();
```