# Bring popup window to front without gaining focus

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I bring my windows form to the front without it gaining focus. I want to achieve something like Steams small popup windows in the corners, and it should stay there even if other windows are focused, but without taking any focus. Right now I'm using this to bring it to the front: `[DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern Int32 SetForegroundWindow(int hWnd);
        SetForegroundWindow(Handle.ToInt32());`

But the problem with this is that it is taking focus and whenever I click on a window in the background, this popup window gets minimized. So this is basically what I want with the window:

• Bring to front
• Don't gain focus
• Stay in front (still without focus) even if other windows are clicked
Please help!

Comment: See [Opening a form in C# without focus](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10727337/719186)

Comment: That helped me. Thanks!