# ShowWindow and messageloop

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I'm using ShowWindow from user32.dll to show messenger style popups ( always on top, doesn't steal focus ), but I can't get them to respond. It seems that my new form is missing a messageloop, and therefore cannot draw it's controls or react to input.

I've tried to create the form in a backgroundworker, but that doesn't seem to help (form still stays unresponsive).

If I show the form with Application.Run(myForm), I get the messageloop and responding form, but no always-on-top+do-not-steal-focus functionality.

So my question is, how do I create a messageloop for my form?

Comment: For now, I'll go with Application.DoEvents. It isn't the most elegant solution, but atm the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156046/show-a-form-without-stealing-focus-in-c) SO post on how to show a form without stealing focus.  This should help

Further down in the answers you can see:

```
protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation
{
   get
   {
      return true;
   }
}
```

Then just do form.Show() and you should get a message pump with an inactive window.

Comment: That uses ShowWindow, which doesn't give me a messageloop and the created form doesn't do anything.

Comment: I added the section form the answer that should work without ShowWindow that will give you a message pump

Comment: I also realized that I can do Application.Run() after ShowWindow to get a message pump for my form.