# Show form without losing focus

Tags: vb.net

I've created a small form that acts like the office notifications (fades in\out above the notification icon tray)

I'm having problems showing this form, I want to display it without the focus being taken from my main application (or any other form), I've managed to get the attached code doing roughly this, (using Me.Activate to take back focus) But this isn't great - focus switches for an instant plus I want to show the form from various areas in my application...

```
  Dim frm2 As New frmNotification()
    frm2.TopMost = True
    frm2.Show()
    Me.Activate()
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: What happens if you don't use Me.Activate ?

Comment: The child form (frm2) is created and takes focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar question has been answered here.

[Show a Form without stealing focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156046/show-a-form-without-stealing-focus-in-c/156159#156159)

The code is in c#, let me know if you need help in converting it to vb.net. Sorry for the delay.