# C# Disable mouse takeover

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cnc

I am currently using the windows on screen keyboard to control the program for the cnc machine. In C# I tried to make a simple on screen keyboard with only the keys I need. I use this command to send key

```
SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```

or

```
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

The first click works, but then the background program "takes away" the mouse after the click and then I can no longer control it. While such a problem does not occur on the windows on screen keyboard
Is there a way to avoid this, to make it work like microsoft osk?
Thanks

Comment: The keyword here is Focus - How about this: [How do I create an "unfocusable" form in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037250/how-do-i-create-an-unfocusable-form-in-c)

Comment: Again background program take mouse and it stuck in corner