# How do I prevent the original form from losing focus when I show another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, focus

I am having a problem where my main form loses focus when opening a new form. I know I can revert the focus back by using `mainForm.focus()`, but how do I handle things if I want the main form to never give up its focus when new window is opened?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show a Form without stealing focus (in C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156046/show-a-form-without-stealing-focus-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show a Form without stealing focus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156046/show-a-form-without-stealing-focus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cody Gray answered this, I'm just expanding it by directly pasting the code. Someone with edit rights can copy it over there and delete this for all I care ;)

pinvoke.net's ShowWindow method.:

```
    private const int SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4;
    private const int HWND_TOPMOST = -1;
    private const uint SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(
         int hWnd,           // window handle
         int hWndInsertAfter,    // placement-order handle
         int X,          // horizontal position
         int Y,          // vertical position
         int cx,         // width
         int cy,         // height
         uint uFlags);       // window positioning flags

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    static void ShowInactiveTopmost(Form frm)
    {
        ShowWindow(frm.Handle, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
        SetWindowPos(frm.Handle.ToInt32(), HWND_TOPMOST,frm.Left, frm.Top, frm.Width, frm.Height,SWP_NOACTIVATE);
        frm.TopMost = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this by overriding the property [`ShowWithoutActivation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showwithoutactivation.aspx) in order for it to return `true` in the forms that you want to show without stealing focus from the form that shown it, in your case that would be your main form.

Comment: Note that you have to override this property for each form that you want to be shown without activation, not on your main form. Otherwise, precisely correct. +1