# VS 2013 Quick Find loses focus when switching to my application - how do I preserve/restore it programmatically?

Tags: c#, xaml, focus

I have whipped up a C# clipboard application that stores multiple 'clippings' for later use. I use low-level keyboard hooks to pop open my application's window(s) on command. When the window is closed (or a clipping is double-clicked), it is supposed to paste the selected clipping into the last active window (the window prior to my application's window). I use low-level WINAPI methods to determine the last active application, snag its handle, and then return focus to it before simulating a Ctrl+V keystroke to paste.

This typically works except in one very unique scenario: I am in a WPF application project, Quick Finding in a XAML file, the cursor automatically switches to the body text, not the Quick Find textbox, and pastes it there. It seems to have something to do with the loss of focus/activation, as it moves the cursor whenever I activate another window, regardless of my own application's running.

VB files, C# files, what have you, and XAML opened in WinForm projects do not steal the Quick Find focus when switching between the VS2013 application and my own; upon returning to the last active application, the text pastes into the Quick Find box.

Only the XAML in WPF application projects gives me this problem.

So far. I know it is a fringe case, but I expect to run into more. This program is meant to be used in a coding environment and it's pretty important that it be able to handle these kinds of scenarios.

I've tried getting the internal control handle using code from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34752/Control-in-Focus-in-Other-Processes, so that I can return the focus to it, but it seems that the handle for the body text and the handle for the Quick Find text box are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial solution is found in: [How do I prevent the original form from losing focus when I show another form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679013/how-do-i-prevent-the-original-form-from-losing-focus-when-i-show-another-form?rq=1) The popup window I use is navigated primarily through my low-level shortcuts, and therefore has no need of explicit activation.

Using the mouse on it or any of my other windows (as I expect my users will sometime), will cause it to gain activation and circumvent this fix. However, it's such a fringe case it doesn't seem to matter. Hopefully this helps anyone in a similar situation (if not necessarily specifically this one).