# How to position a form on top of another form without taking the focus

Tags: c#, winforms

My application needs to display a popup near the cursor position of any active application when certain conditions are met (known by my app).

So I would like to display the form (without stealing the focus from the active application). I tried using ShowWindow with the SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE param but, this way, the my form is displayed under the currently active form.

How can I force my form to be displayed on top of any form active on the screen without stealing the input focus?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show a Form without stealing focus (in C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156046/show-a-form-without-stealing-focus-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to use the [TopMost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost.aspx) property of the form you want to stay on top.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a bit of plumbing to the pop-up form so you can override the WM_ACTIVATE message:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_ACTIVATE)
        {
            if (((int)m.WParam & 0xFFFF) != WA_INACTIVE)
            {
                if (m.LParam != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    SetActiveWindow(m.LParam);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Could not find sender, just in-activate it.
                    SetActiveWindow(IntPtr.Zero);
                }
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Make sure you add the following to your pop-up form as well:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private extern static IntPtr SetActiveWindow(IntPtr handle);
    private const int WM_ACTIVATE = 6;
    private const int WA_INACTIVE = 0;
```

You can use the pop-up form as you would any other, by calling Show() on it. You can make it the top-most window through the TopMost property, as with other forms.

Comment: I tried another approach. Doing a showWindow(NO_ACTIVATE) and then called the SetWindowPosition API and it looks like it's working fine (but I had to attach the process to the input of the active application). I haven't tested your code but will your approach create any flickering in the active window?

Comment: I use it for Outlook-style pop-ups (like when a new mail arrives). There is no flicker. My  popup appears, and fades out after a while, and I have tested it with *lots* of popups without visual disturbance.