# Show a window without setting focus

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

I want to show a window as a notify window (without using NotifyIcon), but I don't want the current application to lose focus when it is shown. How I can do that?
I'm using:

```
private void alert(string msg = "", string link = "", bool bip = true)
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        Form2.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is a notify window?

Comment: Does just setting .visible = true focus the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156046/show-a-form-without-stealing-focus) shows how to "Show a Form without stealing focus" by overriding the CreateParams method.