# Create windows without automatic focus in C#/wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a C#/wpf application which call a webservice every xx minutes. If the webservices reponds, I create a new windows that show (or not) a notifaction situated at the bottom right of the screen.

My problem is that when this notification window is created, the user looses the focus of the main window.

However, I need this notification window to be focusable if the user click somewhere on it. I just don't want it to be foccused when opening.

Is there a way to create this window and tell it not to get focus as creation?

Comment: I've just spent about 5 second to find solution

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156046/show-a-form-without-stealing-focus

Comment: Thanks winko, I think my english is not good enough to seach for the right question with other words.