# How to show new form without disabling the parent form?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have shown a new form in button click on parent form like below,

[image]

Here the background parent form gets disabled when a new child form is activated.

Is there any available options to show the child form without disabling the parent form?

Regards,

Comment: How do you open the new form?

Comment: Use `Form.Show()` instead of `Form.ShowDialog()`?

Comment: childForm.Visible or ChildForm.Show or childForm.ShowDialog

Comment: @MatthewWatson - Form.Show also results the same. I dont want the parentform to get deactivated. I.e the parent form looks like kind of disabled and activated again once the child form is closed.

Comment: When the child is shown give the focus to the parent.

Comment: @Amal You mean it loses focus? That's how **Windows** works.

Comment: @Amal, in the image you've provided the window is not disabled. It's just not focused. Click on it and it will get the focus again (assuming you used `Form.Show`). You can't have two focused windows, can you ?

Comment: The best you can probably do is [showing the new window without stealing focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156046/show-a-form-without-stealing-focus), but then the new Window won't be focused. That's how Windows (and Linux, Mac, etc.) works.

Comment: @john - i have tried the createparams technique proposed to not steal the focus of parent when showing the child, but it is not working.

Comment: OK, is your question that you want the _parent_ to keep focus, and the _child_ not to have focus? Or do you want them _both_ to have focus (you can't - it's impossible).

Comment: yes, i want focus in parent and not in child

Comment: i have set ShowWithoutActivation= true and TopMost= false for child form. and the focus is not disabled for parent perfectly. But when i maximize the parent form and show the child form, child form is not showing.

Answer (score 4):

The `Show` function shows the form in a *non modal* form. This means that you can click on the parent form.

`ShowDialog` shows the form *modally*, meaning you cannot go to the parent form

`Application.Run()` runs the main parent form, and makes that form the main form. Application.Run() is usually found in `main`.

Answer (score 3):

If it is fully disabled (no interaction possible), you are using `.ShowDialog()` on the child form instead of `.Show()`. If you use `.Show()` you will be able to use both forms

**Example:**

```
ChildForm childForm = new ChildForm();
childForm.Show();
```

Comment: I can interact with the parent form, but i dont want the parent look like disabled when child is activated

Comment: @Amal Write a letter to Microsoft then. Name one application that does what your asking.

Answer (score -1):

after you open the new form and call `this.Activate();` it will refocus on the parent window, but this will cause it to loose focus for a fraction of a second

Comment: Thanks for your solution. If we can prevent the focus losing of parent, it will be better.